# Twitter Bootstrap pop-over not working on website: uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have the Twitter Bootstrap "pop-over" working locally on my machine, but once I upload the working JS and HTML to my site it seems to fail.

The site is located at [www.cornerwoodstock.com](http://www.cornerwoodstock.com) and the popover is on the first button.
When I inspect the code, I get a "Uncaught reference error $".

I'm new to JS so any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using jQuery ($) in the middle of the page, but loading jQuery at the end.